# NullReferenceException in static class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application with a static "global" class. Inside of the static class I have a variable called user. When a user logs in a set that variable. Debugging through the log process. All my other static variable seems to be fine except two. I am not sure why I am getting 'GlobalVariables.User' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'.
Can anyone shed some light on this. Thanks

```
namespace GlobalClass

public static class GlobalVariables


public static User User { get; set; }
```

Comment: How does the static User get set, and are you sure that the code that sets it is executing before the reference to it that throws the exception?

Comment: Show us your code! Without that, we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its probably throwing because you didn't create an instance of User. One way to fix it is the following.

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
   static GlobalVariables()
   {
       User = new User();
   }

   public static User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't User just be `null` though, instead of throwing an NRE ?

Comment: @Vache - Unless I've missed something, user is null, so accessing its members will throw a NRE.

Comment: It sure will, but I thought OP was accessing `User`, not its members.

Comment: @Vache - I'm not really certain what he is doing.

Comment: I set the variable User at login, GlobalVariables.User = user;

Comment: Ritch, so a static constructor that set the property User to a new instance of user?

Comment: @user516883 - It seems like user isn't being initialized before you access it. I don't know your particular situation to offer a specific suggest, but adding it to the constructor should fix the exception. FWIW, if you are going to use statics, I'd lean towards ensuring that you have some sort of null object pattern established. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern